# In teradata, can you insert a cte into a table?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I've looked at the other postings but I haven't seen a resolution for this.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS (SELECT * FROM yourtable) with no data ;
```

Then

```
with cte as (
select top 10* from yourtable
)
```

```
insert into newtable

select * from cte

select * from newtable
```

I get an error saying it `expects a select and not an insert.`
How would I accomplish inserting the cte into a table?

Comment: Yes, just make the WITH part of the SELECT not the INSERT

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean.  Could you just post the code?

Comment: `insert into newtable
with cte as (

select top 10* from yourtable)

select * from cte`